# How to retain state during navigation with Next.js and Redux?

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

Using Next.js `next/router` will cause a reload or it will retain Redux state?

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const DashboardSidebar = ({ mobile = false }: Props) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    router.push(
`/${lang}/dashboard/organizations/${organizationId}/events/${id}`
        )
```

Or I should use `redux-persist` to retain state? When I follow this setup:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

I got this error:

> redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.

Do I get it because I use Next.js and SSR?

Shall I move forward and use `next-redux-wrapper`?

https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper

Comment: If using redux is not mandatory then, You can use router.push({ pathname: url, query: data}, url); It won't be showing any query params in the URL too.  

The drawback is you can't pass an object of objects.

Comment: No, you missunderstand, I would use Redux, but not persist it like here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

Here are some instructions: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering#server-side-rendering-with-nextjs

As the user changes routes, the store needs to be rehydrated each time before the html is generated and sent to the client.

I am not a fan of this architecture. It seems strange that the store needs to be filled back up with its state (rehydrated) every time the user needs a new render. Where are you going to persist the store in the meantime? What is its lifecyle?

In a SPA, the lifecycle of the store is when the page refreshes (which would require a programmatic invocation, or the user navigating away and coming back, or pressing Ctrl+R). Conceptually, this is much simpler.